# Upload and Download Files between Windows Local Machine and Linux Remote Machines using Vault SSH Secret Engine

Tags: server, download, upload, scp, hashicorp-vault

Upload and Download Files between Windows Local Machine and Linux Remote Machines using Vault SSH Secret Engine

Hi Team,

Using SCP command how to Upload and Download File between Windows Local Machine and Linux Remote Machines using Vault SSH Secret Engine

Comment: Hi Deepak, welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question reads like you only pasted your assignement. Help us help you by breaking down the task and asking specific questions, in the form "I tried this, I expected that, but this happened instead".